# Add Azure SQL Server in to Azure VNET

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-networking, azure-sql

Is it possible to add Azure SQL Server into a Azure Virtual Network?

Currently I see only a separate firewall for SQL server. But I want to maintain a single Network Security Group and have all my VMs,SQL Servers and AppServices in the VNET.

Just wondering if this is possible with Azure?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not currently possible to join an Azure SQL instance to a vNet. [This user voice item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/5537689-allow-sql-database-to-join-virtual-network-vpn) says it's planned, but that's been in that state for some time (yes I know the title mentions VPN but it is really talking about vNet).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can !

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance

It is even better than the previous offer. 
and by the way you can use private endpoint now to provide secured access to SQL PaaS

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but in 2017, it was not there. So I had to go ahead with a different architecture.